# Error when compiling in AdaGIDE using win32

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm experiencing some troubles with AdaGIDE compiler and its libraries. I installed GNAT 2013 and AdaGIDE 7.45 on Windows XP. When I'm trying to compile any code that requires win32 (eg. `with win32.winnt;`) AdaGIDE's console says `file "win32.ads" not found`.

I searched the web and I found [this](http://objectmix.com/ada/248053-win32-ads-not-found-error.html), followed the instructions, installed the win32 package, ran setpath.bat, I even tried copying libraries into every GNAT folder I found - but nothing works. When I copy win32.ads to the folder with my program it requires more libraries so I guess copying all of them into my program directory wouldn't be a very good idea either.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

-- Edit --

I had a little chat with the creator of AdaGIDE and all I had to do was to set Compiler Options in Tools -> Project setting in current directory to:

> -Ic:\GNAT\2012\include\win32ada -Ic:\gnat\2012\lib\win32ada\static

c:\GNAT\2012\include\win32ada is where I installed Win32Ada, you also have to make sure that in `\static\` there is a file named `libwin32ada.a`.

Unfortunately it has to be repeated for every new project.

Answer (score 1):

As I write, libre.adacore.com is only showing the 2012 (and 2011!) releases. I expect the 2013 release will be back in a day or so.

Looking at the 2012 release for x86-windows, I see the eleventh entry on the list is "Win32Ada 2012". I think the 2013 version of that is what you need.

You *might* be able to install the 2012 version of Win32Ada into your 2013 GNAT installation ... worth a try if you can't wait!

In any case, Win32Ada is provided in a way that expects you to use GNAT Project (`.gpr`) files. It comes with examples: if you look in `C:\GNAT\2012\share\examples\win32ada`, you'll find various example projects; I tried `connect`, double-clicked on `connect.gpr`, it fired up *GPS*, I said *Build>Project>Build All* and it built `connect.exe`.

Comment: Yesterday on the page there was only 2012 and 2013 versions available. Nevertheless, just now I installed 2012 versions of GNAT, Win32Ada and new AdaGIDE on another computer and it doesn't work either nor does installing Win32Ada with GNAT 2013 - still the same message when I compile...